# What is the best design pattern to update a view from another class in a kotlin android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, capacitor

I have a hybrid app built with capacitor, however I need to implement some native code to use the android Presentation class to use a secondary display. I need to update my presentation view based on data received from capacitor, what is the best design pattern to achieve this?

Here's my adapter

```
class CartItemAdapter(context: Context, private val cartItems: List<CartItem>) : ArrayAdapter<CartItem>(context, 0, cartItems) {
  override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customer_list_item, parent, false)

    val item = getItem(position) ?: return view // Safely unwrapping

    // Bind the view elements to your data
    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.itemDescription).text = item.description

    return view
  }
}
```

and here is my capacitor plugin method that get's called and receives data from capacitor:

````
  @PluginMethod
  fun transactionChange(call: PluginCall){
    val itemsJson = call.getString("items")
    println(itemsJson)

    val transaction = itemsJson?.let { Json.decodeFromString<Transaction>(it) }
    transaction?.let {

    }
    val ret = JSObject()
    ret.put("items", transaction)
    call.resolve(ret)
  }
  suspend fun login(): User {
    val credentials = Credentials.anonymous()
    return app.login(credentials)
  }
}```

What is the best way to update my view in the seperate class?


I have tried calling a companion method, however that requires a context and I understand that passing that context in is an anti pattern, I'm just trying to find the correct design pattern for this.
````

Comment: Typically, updating a view from a class other than the owner of the view (the activity or fragment) is something you would never want to do because of the principle of separation of concerns. Doing that will turn your code into spaghetti with classes all having to be interconnected and knowing what each other are doing. I’m not familiar with what capacitor is, but probably it needs to provide some way for other classes to subscribe to changes with a listener interface. Then the view owner (activity or fragment) can subscribe to changes and update the associated view accordingly.

Comment: Maybe you already have that by exposing the suspend function. If that’s the case, the activity or fragment should call the suspend function in a coroutine and update the view with the return value.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I agree and would like to use an activity or fragment to update my view. However the issue is that Android Presentation class (the android class for presenting on a  second display) is not a fragment or an activity and displays a like so: setContentView(R.layout.customer_display) Maybe I'm just not understanding as I am very new to android native development, is there a way I could use Presentation to display an activity?

Comment: No, a Presentation is a Dialog. Nothing can host an Activity. But what I said about activities or fragments also applies to presentation--it's your view owner.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a great answer because I've never used Presentation and didn't test this. But I would think that just like with an Activity or Fragment, you set the content view, then acquire references to the views within it that you need and do things to them.

Unfortunately,  `lifecycleScope`, the typical way to run coroutines in your UI layer, won't be available since it's not an Activity or Fragment. So you need to create a CoroutineScope for that and cancel it when the Presentation is destroyed to avoid leaks.

So I think your code will look vaguely like this:

```
class MyPresentation(
    display: Display,
    context: Context
) : Presentation(context, display) {

    private val scope = MainScope()
    init {
        setOnDismissListener { scope.cancel() }
    }

    // ...

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.customer_display)

        val recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        val adapter = CartItemAdapter(context, emptyList())
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        // I don't know anything about Capacitor but let's assume you have some
        // sort of reference to it here.

        scope.launch {
            val loginResult = capacitorPlugin.login()
            // do something with login result, maybe update some views?
            val dataList = capacitorPlugin.getSomeData()
            adapter.cartItems = dataList // you'll have to make cartItems a public var
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

}
```